# Android : Logging all API calls

Tags: android, dalvik

I'm working on a collage project about security in Android. One part of the project attempts to capture and log all API function called by the selected APK. This can't be done with a external programs so in the project we are working with the Android source code to modify the ROM.

At the present time we only have two possible solutions:

DVM JNI Bridge

The API is Java code so, obviously, the Dalvik Virtual Machine needs a bridge to execute JNI code.  The function which handle all cases is dvmCallJNIMethod(const u4* args, JValue* pResult, const Method* method, Thread* self). In this function we can get the name and the class of the called function.

This function can log all the JNI code executed, which includes API calls. But there is no easy way to distinct between private calls and API calls. And, if we wanted to execute some code depending on the risk of the API call executed, we would have to create a huge and inefficient switch.

API Framework

another solution To log all API calls is creating a new interface for the framework. With a new logging class and a simple inheritance should be easy to log all calls and add a risk parameter. But it would mean changing a lot of code. Also, Java code has worst performance than C, so it might not be the most efficient way.

More over, we would like to ask you a few questions about Android DVM and the API.

1.Which is exactly the call flow between DVM and the API?
2.Could be the DVM monitor a good idea to log the calls?
3.Which role have the shared libraries in all of this?
4.Are all API calls really Java code?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: One would think that, as a base assumption, any case where an app invokes code not packaged as part of that app is an "API".  This would suggest inserting oneself in the linkage between apps and the actual functionality provided by the platform.  Alternatively, if one is interested in a permission-level view, then going after the `interprocess communication` through `binder` (and a handful of other mechanisms) may be more interesting.  But this will tend to be harder to decipher as it is not public APIs but rather platform-provided stubs in the app process talking to system code.

Comment: The JNI call bridge is only used for executing methods declared `native`.  If you want to intercept all method calls you should look at how the "traceview" method profiling stuff works.  By replacing dalvik/vm/Profile.c[pp] with code that does whatever it is you need to do, you will be assured of seeing all called methods.  As @ChrisStratton pointed out, you can do a first-order check on "public API" by comparing `method->clazz->pDvmDex`.  You will be executing in the "debug" interpreter, so there will be a performance hit.

Comment: For me the API refers to Android's API (which can be found in developer section) so @ChrisStratton idea can't help me. But thx both for your answer. I'll try to see how the profiler work and make something similar.

Comment: @Marc - that's precisely why I was suggesting you go after the linkage between code provided by the package, and code not provided by it.  Note that this is a different slicing than the alternative one of code running in the app process, vs code running in a system process on the other side of Binder or other IPC.  Presumably for the first, you could do it by wrapping and renaming all the system-provided classes.  Ie, instead of android.app.Activity you would extend wrapper.android.app.Activity and so on.  But fadden's idea of using built in debugging hooks sounds easier to set up.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm not quite understand this. The linkage between APK's and the API isnt done inside the DVM? You idea is interesting but could not see how it can be done.

Comment: The linkage between code you provide and code the platform provides could be intercepted at compile time.  For example, by automatically renaming everything used by your program to wrapped versions.  But that may not be the most efficient approach given that it sounds like you can use platform instrumentation at runtime.